# Function context when calling via arguments

Tags: javascript

I've got this interview question and can't really get what the difference between `fn()` an `arguments[0]()` since they both reference to the same function.

```
var length = 10;

function foo() {
  console.log(this.length);
}

var obj = {
  length: 5,
  method: function(fn) {
    fn(); // TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    arguments[0](); // 2
  }
};

obj.method(foo, 1);
```

Ok, so when calling `arguments[0]()`, in `foo` it's context (this) will be equal to function arguments - `[Arguments] { '0': [Function: foo], '1': 1 }`. But how is this happend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```js
function foo() {
  console.log(this.bar);
}

const obj =  {
  bar: "foobar",
  myFunction: foo
}

obj.myFunction(); // foobar
obj["myFunction"](); // also `foobar`
```

In the above, the  `this` in the function `foo` gets bound to the calling context of foo, in the case above, that is the object `obj` because that's where the function `myFunction` is being invoked from, and so `this` inside of the function `foo` will refer to `obj`.

In your case, `arguments` is an [*object*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments#Description) in a similar way to how `obj` above is an objct. It has a bunch of properties such as its `length` as well as numeric properties to represent indexes for the arguments passed into the function. For example, you could (roughly) make your own arguments object like so:

```js
function foo() {
  console.log(this.length);
}

const myArguments =  {
  0: foo,
  length: 2
};

// myArguments.0() is syntactically invalid, so we can only use bracket-notation like below
myArguments[0](); // 2
```

Notice that the above `myArguments[0]()` is using the same idea of calling a function from the first code snippet (`obj.myFunction()` & `obj["myFunction"]()`), as we are using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) (`arguments[0]`) (rather than [dot-notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation) (`arguments.0`)) to access and call the function stored at the property `0` from the object `myArguments`. Thus, the calling context for `foo` in this case is `myArguments`, and as a result that is what `this` gets bound to within the function `foo`.

The same idea above applies to your code. When you call `fn()` without an explicit context (as you're not inovking it from an object by having it prefixed with `someObject.`, or using methods such as `.bind()`, `.call()` or `.apply()`) the `this` within your `foo()` function will be `undefined` (if in [strict-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)), thus causing your error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

However, when using `arguments[0]`, the `this` gets bound to the `arguments` object, much like in the above two examples.

Comment: Why is it specifically 2? The output?

Comment: @ZameerAnsari-xameeramir because `method(foo, 1)` is called with **2** arguments `foo` and `1`. So `arguments` inside of the `method` function has a `.length` of `2`. Because `arguments[0]()` calls `foo`, it sets `foo`'s `this` value to be the `arguments` object of the `method` function, so the `foo` function prints the length (number of arguments) passed to `method`.

Answer (score 4):

The `this` value used by an execution context depends on how a function was called.

```js
1.  fn() // TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
2.  arguments[0]() // 2
```

Line 1 shows a direct function invocation. For this style the `this` value will be undefined in strict mode and the global object in non-strict mode.

Line 2 shows a function being invoked as a method. It is a bit of a trick question because we are more used to seeing the dot operator used with methods, but the [bracket property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) notation works similarly. When you invoke a function as a method, the `this` value is set to be the object the method is invoked on. This behavior is designed to support object-oriented style programming.

It's akin to writing `arguments.0()`, but the JS syntax does not permit this sequence (presumably due to ambiguity with the decimal place syntax).

Sneaky interview question!

Comment: Yeah, this similarity between calling via dot and brackets (and having method context preserving) may not be obvious. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Why is it specifically 2? The output?

Answer (score 0):

here obj work like an array, get value on given position and call it as a function

```js
var length = 10;

function foo1() {
  console.log(length);
}

function foo2() {
  console.log(this.length);
}

const obj = {
  length: 5,
  0: foo1,
  1: foo2,
};

obj[0](); // 10
obj[1](); // 5
```