# Function return is not returning correct value after execution inside IIFE

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, iife

I asked a question, to which a friend marked as duplicate, though I feel that either I was not able to explain well my question OR the dupe doesn't explain it well.

Reference: [Getting wrong value in variable after execution of IIFE (with a function parameter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67747262/getting-wrong-value-in-variable-after-execution-of-iife-with-a-function-paramet?noredirect=1#comment119747416_67747262)

The question I asked was simply, that if `this` inside IIFE points to window, then why doesn't the function execution itself returns the value of `this` does the same? Why I am getting a different return?

```js
var foo = {
  bar: function() { 
    return this; 
  },
  baz: 1
};

var a = (function(){
    console.log(this); //returns window
    return arguments[0](); //returns function definition. Why? Should return window
})(foo.bar);

console.log(a);
```

Remember, I am not using arrow-function of ES6, so context is not binded. Also, I am not using either of Call, Apply, Bind. So, context is not carried, only Function-definition is carried. So, expected answer should be `window-object` (as the line above), which is not being returned. Why?

Comment: Please [edit your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67747262/edit) to get it reopened, instead of reposting a slightly different version of it. The precise question you added here makes it answerable, instead of being a generic "*Please explain how the `this` keyword gets its value in my code*".

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64462288/5648954) question, it might help